# "debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages

Tags: apt, debconf

I'm trying to install the `flashybrid` but when I enter the `apt-get install flashybrid` command, I get this error:

```
root@user-desktop:/home/user# apt-get install flashybrid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
flashybrid is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up flashybrid (0.15+nmu2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing flashybrid (--configure):
subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
flashybrid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried this one to find what is already using that file:

```
root@user-desktop:/home/user# lsof | grep /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/user/.gvfs
Output information may be incomplete.
dpkg-prec 4672 root 4rW REG 8,6 39658 1697827 /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

But I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 285):

A solution to this locking problem is [detailed in the wiki](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/DebuggingInstallationIssues):

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Will show you what process is holding the lock:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root      18210 F.... dpkg-preconfigu
```

Then you simply need to note down the PID and kill it like so:

```
sudo kill PID
sudo kill -9 PID  # if the first doesn't work
```

Comment: This worked fantastic! Thanks a bunch, I didn't know of 'fuser'!

Comment: fuser also has the option switch `-k` which kills the found process that uses the file:
`sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` will kill the process right away

Comment: This should be selected as best answer.

Comment: Worked for me when an upgrade of Debian from Stretch to Buster accidentally got backgrounded.

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. However the process holds the file after restart and I have to manually kill it after every restart. Do you have any idea?

Comment: this worked well thank you so much, brother, I just learned a new thing called fuser!

Comment: @ZuraSekhniashvili same with me~

Comment: For me, the process holding the lock was `/usr/sbin/needrestart`. Amusingly enough, I was trying to run that command myself and was being blocked. I had a network-interrupted `apt-get upgrade` and had only been looking for `apt-get` processes to kill. It hadn't occurred to me to look for `needrestart` as well.

Answer (score 126):

This is more simple one command

I just did:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

After I run the `apt-get install` and (I was installing curl  ) and it worked restored the db manual pages.

PS: I removed something with apt-get and I did have this problem.
but solved it simply thank also to @rajagenupula

Comment: I used `sudo \rm -v /var/cache/debconf/*.dat`

Comment: Don't do this... you can break your system. The correct answer is to use fuser and kill the process, as in Sayed's answer below.

Comment: Um, don't delete that. Just kill the process that has the file opened.

Comment: This could be very dangerous thing to do. Please see answer below

Comment: Can someone explain what `config.dat`, `passwords.dat` and `templates.dat` are? These are the three files the command here will delete. I ended up using the other answer below, but slightly curious why you'd need to delete all three files here.

Comment: In my case, there was no process running, so this was the only solution that worked.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked for me, i was updating openssh-server

Comment: It works fine for me on Debian9 Stretch

Comment: worked for me, using `Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 2022.3`  thanks.

Answer (score 17):

1. open your terminal
2. open the location `/var/cache/debconf` with `gksu nautilus`
3. move (cut/paste) all of the .dat files to another backup directory.
4. attempt to run again (will likely get a different error)
5. restore those dat files from the aforementioned backup directory.
6. Then try again what you were doing (should work this time).

Comment: I had a similar problem and I just deleted all the files in the debconf folder.

Comment: i said there at point 3 . a file with password and with extension . ok now what you're getting . could you post them here by pastebin link .

Comment: same problem, I needed to remove all files in debconf folder

Comment: i am still getting the error debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory apt-extracttemplates failed

Comment: I was getting really quite angry, saw your answer and suddenly there's progress. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo fuser -vik /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Will display the process and ask if you want to terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a process still running blocking debconf. **You should wait until it finish**. Or find out how it got stuck, since in some cases it will be try to ask you a question but since you don't have a scope to see it. If you wait sometime and things doesn't change you may need to reboot the system, or terminate the process.

```
sudo kill 4672
```

or

```
sudo killall dpkg-prec
```

This will assure you that your database will not get damaged and will prevent further problems.

Comment: I think it's pointless to use process id 4672 in your first command example. Somebody might use that command as-is, but it won't work as he would very likely have a different process id.

Comment: @user205301 that's what the second is for ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in an unattended script, make sure you don't accidentally have two consecutive `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` commands running, otherwise the second command can fail to obtain the lock and thus end up in this error.