# Cannot install apt-fast

Tags: apt-fast

During installation of apt-fast the screen looped and after a while I closed the window.

How can I fix it?

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up apt-fast (1.7.2-1~precise1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing apt-fast (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-fast
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lock file and run.

To remove the lock:
`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up apt-fast (1.7.2-1~precise1) ...

debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing apt-fast (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 apt-fast

Comment: Did you remove the lock file before running the command?

Comment: Yes, I removed!!!

Comment: Can you past the output of `ps axgrep dpkg` . With that we can see what is creating the lock issue.

Comment: ps ax|grep dpkg

16864 pts/6    Ss+    0:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 147 --configure aria2:amd64 apt-fast:amd64

16865 pts/6    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-fast.postinst configure 

16871 pts/6    S+     0:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-fast.config configure

Comment: okay. Can you reboot the machine and run the command once?

Comment: I cannot reboot, ...

Comment: I killed the three running application, removed the lock file again and purged apt-fast, ... now it is ok again.

Thanks!

Comment: Good that you got the fix.