# Cannot delete apt-fast for a clean install

Tags: apt-fast

This is my problem:

```
$ destroy apt-fast
[sudo] password for colbyryptos: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apt-fast is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up man-db (2.6.1-2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, followed by `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

It then gives me this

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for colbyryptos: 
Setting up man-db (2.6.1-2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
```

Comment: Is `destroy` an alias in your bash? or something? we are confused!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 3):

I think, `apt-fast` is running in background thus locking the process. You have two options:

1. Restart your PC and try again. (*This is the best*).
2. Or Delete the `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` file using the command

   ```
    sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
   ```

<sup>I am not going to recommend this method, because it may cause problem</sup>

Comment: thanks actually the restart worked like a charm      ... also sorry i forget to mention that destroy was an alias for sudo apt-get remove sry about the confussion