# Error processing libc6:i386 and libtinfo5:i386 while trying to install anything "/var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked..."

Tags: apt, dpkg, synaptic

When I try to install anything through apt-get or synaptic I keep on getting this output

```
...
Fetched 23.6 MB in 1min 10s (336 kB/s)                                         
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libc6:i386 (2.15-0ubuntu10.3) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing libc6:i386 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtinfo5:i386:
 libtinfo5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libtinfo5:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:i386
 libtinfo5:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Hope this help http://askubuntu.com/a/137265/9701

Comment: I'll be damned, it works ...but I had to remove all the files in the /var/cache/debconf

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working answer in the question comment ...thank you Achu and Ican

---

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*   #no wories it's just a cache folder 
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I had a similar issue on Dell XPS 15 today.
` sudo dpkg --configure -a` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 15.10 on a DELL XPS Developer edition laptop :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
```

Removing files from /var/cache/debconf did not really work for me. I kept getting the error every time i ran an upgrade.

Comment: It really works for me too