# 12.10 won't complete update says config.dat is locked by another process

Tags: 12.10, updates

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 man-db
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This has been asked before :) 1 of them: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214081/dpkg-returned-an-error-code1-for-libc6i386-and-libtinfo5i386-while-trying-to?rq=1 and another one with a bit more answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!