# Installing Epson Printer but Interrupted by lsb Dependency Error

Tags: drivers, apt, software-installation, printing, scanner

I am installing the Epson XP-310 driver from [this website](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=227224&BV_UseBVCookie=yes&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_O_LINUX).

When I attempt to install the downloaded `.deb` file, I get the following error:

```
The Package System is broken 

epson-inkjet-printer-201303w:i386: Depends: lsb(>=3.2) but 4.1+Debian11ubuntu is installed
```

I'm very confused. It says I must have lsb version >=3.2 but I have 4.1.
Why am I getting the dependency error?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with my Epson WF-3520 and the driver from the Epson-Website. This solved my problem:

Try, to make sure the damaged driver will be removed:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

And then install the driver from the package manager

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-escpr
```

I installed the package "printer-driver-escpr" version 1.3.0-1 with the package manager and the driver works for me with the Epson WF-3520.

Now, try to install your epson printer.

Comment: This fixed my problem for a slightly different lsb dependency issue

Comment: Bro, You saved my life.
Do you want to get party just say.
I was having this issue on my kali linux 2021.1 and trying to solve for 2 days but finally soved.
thanks man

Comment: I tried this for my L555. My L555 got installed as a Generic Text only Printer. Then I went to Printer details and Updated the Driver from Database. The database had a close-enough printer - L455. So I set that one as the driver. Printer started working fine.

Comment: This worked for me with L3156 , but I had to remove the printer and add it again after installing the driver. Before I did that, the printer showed up as a generic Epson printer and trying to print a test page just paused forever. After removing and readding the printer (automatically detected) it correctly identified the printer by series and printed the test page perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

I was having an awful problem installing my Epson printer in Ubuntu 16.04 I had messages dependences not met `lsb3.2` in the ubuntu software center; the same message for gdebi. I will point out at this time the gnome software center apart from being short of a number of packages I have previously used does not show the missing dependences so I installed the two mentioned above. They were not really a lot of use with the exception of telling me there were unmet dependences in the end  what I did was to install `alien`:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Then I went to [the Epson site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX), entered my printer which was `Wf -7610` and clicked the search a list came up with `deb`s or `rpm`s - I downloaded the `rpm`.

Went to the download folder and opened in terminal and ran:

```
sudo alien -i your_epson_printer_package_file.rpm
```

Then switched off my printer and went to settings and deleted it.

Restarted the printer it was immediately recognized. then printed a test page, worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Just had this exact problem. The 'fix' was to simply download the right version of the drivers - there are 32 and 64 bit versions provided on this site: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/.

I had downloaded the 32 bit (because I hadn't read the filename, just saw `.deb` and downloaded) but actually needed the 64 bit version - maybe the OP did the same?

I should also point out that, when I used the site, it took a bit of patience to get it to work (lots of 503 errors, download buttons not showing up etc...) but if you keep at it then it'll work in the end :).

Answer (score 1):

Try  `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then  clean the cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: Tried just as you said but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a while got tired of not printing.

First of all install alien. This is package converting tool that changed rpm to deb-files and vice versa.

```
$ sudo apt-get install alien
```

Convert the file to RPM using alien:

```
$ sudo alien --to-rpm  /path/to/epson-inkjet-printer-201303w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb --scripts
epson-inkjet-printer-201303w-1.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm generated
```

Use the `--scripts` parameter to include the scripts. Then take that same .rpm file you just converted and convert it back to .deb

```
$ sudo alien --to-deb /path/to/epson-inkjet-printer-201303w-1.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm --scripts
epson-inkjet-printer-201303w_1.0.0-3_amd64.deb generated
```

I guess you could alternatively run the file as an rpm.

```
$ sudo alien -i package_file.rpm
```

Where the `-i` will run install the rpm-file directly.

After this I was able to install the package successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Using synaptic, I installed incrementally lsb, lsb-release, lsb-printing, lsb-cxx, lsb-graphics, lsb-desktop, and lsb-core (some of which were pre-installed). The shotgun approach failed each time. Until I installed lsb-pkgchk3. Bingo. I'm lovin' my Epson WF-3520 on fully-up-to-date 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the installation of the driver `epson-inkjet-printer-stylus-office-tx510fn-series` produced the same error. Important to notice in my case was:

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by 
another process: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar
```

Hence I found [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t) regarding the locked `.dat` file. With the command

`sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat`

I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I coldn't get my Epson to print under Ubuntu 16.04, so I worked around this by doing a manual install of the LSB:

Note that I got the files from the **br** server as a live in Brazil, you may get from another server that suits you best. Another note is that I got the *_amd64.deb* versions, you may need *_i386.deb* if you're running under a 32 bit enviroment, if that's the case consider that the *_all.deb* remain unchanged.

Files required:

from ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpegturbo:

- libjpeg62-turbo_1.4.80-115-gfb907b2-1_amd64.deb

ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb:

- lsb-core_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-cxx_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-desktop_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-graphics_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-invalid-mta_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb
- lsb-languages_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-multimedia_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-printing_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb-release_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb
- lsb-security_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
- lsb_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb

Then I used gdebi to install the packages:

```
sudo gdebi *package*
```

starting with libjpeg62turbo and then following by:

```
sudo gdebi lsb*
```

It constantly yelled at me complaining about dependencies, when it asked I installed that package first, and tried that last command again. After the process was over I could install my Epson printer trouble free and it works perfectly.

if gdebi is not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Someone more skilled than me can streamline the process... If I could check the order that the packages need to be installed I could write a script that does this process automagically. But it'll have to wait because right now I can't uninstall all of that and disable my printer in the process.

Cheers.

Comment: -1 **This is dangerous advice!** Replacing `lsb*` packages of one distro with those from another can and will lead to various difficult to foresee problems.

Comment: I'm not really **replacing** the lsb packages because it is not available in Ubuntu 16.04, and after following lots of advice elsewhere this was the only way I could get my Epson L355 printer working, and that is critical to me. Maybe someone could make a PPA?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and i've downloaded and installed the lsb-core package for Ubuntu 14.04, and it works.

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main" && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lsb-core
-y
```

Then, try to install epson-inkjet-printer-201303w again.

Comment: Did this and it still failed with unmet dependencies trying to install lsb-core.  Had to then do "apt-get -f install" which then installed 2 or 3 dozen more packages.  After that I was able to install my Epson XP-820 printer via the GUI.  Very messy IMHO.