# What would have to happen when closing the EULA agreement in the terminal to install wine?

Tags: 10.04

I was in the EULA agreement terminal to install wine and then I closed it and I dont know how to bring it back to get wine to finish installing. I think it asked if I wanted to terminate it or something along the line when I closed the terminal. What do I need to do?

Comment: Please do not edit your question if you have a new problem.  Post separate questions. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your question.

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg-reconfigure` on your package should prompt you to accept the EULA agreement again.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure <your package>
```

Execute :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wine
```

Comment: it shows this after the help you gave me.                              debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: See here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t ;)

Comment: After I saw that it said that wine was not in the system, I had to reboot and then it asked me to put it in manual when I put: sudo apt-get install wine