# Interrupted apt-get, can't use apt/dpkg

Tags: apt, dpkg, lock

I was installing lamp-server^ with the command

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

when it hung on this section:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto                          mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
```

I tried ctrl+c to no avail, and then out of habbit hit ctrl-z, which suspended it or something. Using fg it instantly exited but left dpkg in an odd locked state.

I tried,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

both before and after

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

but to no avail. If I try --configure -a or apt-get upgrade I get this:

```
theelous3@compoopr:/var/lib/dpkg/updates$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php7.0:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-cli; however:
  Package php7.0-cli is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 libapache2-mod-php7.0 depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
 libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-mysql:
 php7.0-mysql depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-mysql:
 php-mysql depends on php7.0-mysql; however:
  Package php7.0-mysql is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-json
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-cli
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 libapache2-mod-php
 mysql-server
 php7.0-mysql
 php-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 2):

You have left packages in an unconfigured state. You'd need to remove the lock files left from debconf, and fix unconfigured packages.

`sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Uh. I can't see how to edit that comment. I fixed it by manually running `apt-get remove` and removing all of the packages listed above, then removing the lock files as you said, and finally `sudo fuser -vik /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` and killed the process holding it. The apt configure and such. Ty for assist.