# Trying to install software, but I get an error every time ""config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked"

Tags: 16.04, apt

I tried a lot of solutions posted here, but none of them work. I am trying to install vlc. Here's the whole output.

```
:/$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vlc is already the newest version (2.2.2-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu13) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: vlc seems to be installed already (see `vlc is already the newest version`), but there is a problem with configuring package `libpam-systemd`. Issue `fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` to find out which process locks that file.

Comment: @ridgy nothing happens

Comment: What about `sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`?

Comment: @ridgy
`at
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root       8020 F.... frontend
`

Comment: seems you got PID there but give full information to know what is processing using that file.

Comment: @Raja what full information?

Comment: It seems there is some other process running `dpkg` from a frontend(?). You may find out more by `sudo ps -ef | grep 8020` and then stop that process, either by closing ist window (if visible) or by killing the process: `sudo kill 8020` or `sudo kill -9 8020` (the hard way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: @karel This question is 3 years old..I think I solved it somehow but don't remember how.

Answer (score 1):

From the given log report we found that `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` file has been locked by some other process.

We have to release  `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` file from that process.

Open terminal and type `lsof /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` and you would get process name thats been using `config.dat` file and kill that process with either

```
kill <space> PID
```

or

```
kill <space> -9 <space> PID
```

then try again.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This happenes after I do this, 
/$ lsof /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
      Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: @SimeonAleksov try doing it as root user.

Comment: `COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
frontend 8020 root    4uW  REG    8,1    49683 1442713 /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
`

Comment: @SimeonAleksov now try giving kill 8020 or kill -9 8020 as root user.

Comment: Nice, nothing happened after running these commands, I am going to try to install something now.