# Error with libpam-systemd:amd64 dpkg error, locked by another process

Tags: dpkg

On using this command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` this is the output I receive.

```
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu17) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64
```

Please help resolve this I am not able to install anything new using `apt-get`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 7):

try `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat`
it will rebuild the `.dat` files when you run `apt-get` again.