# E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success

Tags: apt, appstream

I am getting the following error when I run `sudo apt update`

```
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: Resolved by refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/380701/424049 or https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/apt-get-upgrade-with-error-debconf-1-5-56-deb8u1-4175619215/#post6342181

Answer (score 63):

Remove libappstream3 with the CLI command

```
sudo apt-get remove libappstream3
```

or

```
sudo apt remove libappstream3
```

Afterwards, apt update should work fine again.

Source: https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6174.0

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge libappstream3`  did the work for me

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: My Debian would uninstall `apt-config-icons* gnome-software* gstreamer1.0-packagekit* libappstream4* packagekit* packagekit-tools*` if I uninstalled libappstream4. This was too risky so I decided to reinstall libappstream4 `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappstream4` and this fixed the problem too.

Comment: On my Ubuntu-Desktop 16.04 I have: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 appstream : Depends: libappstream3 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not going to be installed
 code : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.26) but 2:3.21-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
It's libnss3 cyclic dependency which I can't reinstall but I'm trying.

Comment: And now it's `sudo apt-get purge libappstream4` :)

Comment: try upgrading docker > 20.10.9

Answer (score 6):

(in Matthias' comment https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712/comments/24 on bug #1579712) worked for me.

> Removing `/usr/bin/appstreamcli` is fine if you install the fixed
>   package afterwards.
>
> To install this manually, please do (for amd64, adjust URLs for other
>   architectures):
>
> ```
> cd /tmp && mkdir asfix
> cd asfix
> wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/appstream_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
> wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libappstream3_0.9.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
> ```
>
> This should solve the issue.

Comment: I have had the same problem and the problem was that there was (in my case) an   inaproprietly escaped chacter in  the file /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml on line 265, which broke the xml, hence the error. the line  <checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat" target="content" type="sha1">3ef2bdee8aca2a45b9f53b4d4cce9722523f57f8</checksum> ,
the & symbol must be encoded &amp; for this to be a valid xml

Comment: The comment from @Nikola fixed it for me.

Comment: @aGer yeah it fixes it, bit now another problem, once the list is refreshed, the probem appears again, so this is not a good solution