# update problem in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

```
root@cubic:~# apt update
                                
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'touch /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp 2>/dev/null || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: This is an duplicate question. Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/942895/e-problem-executing-scripts-aptupdatepost-invoke-success for similar issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Problem executing scripts APT Update::Post-Invoke-Success error during apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943463/e-problem-executing-scripts-apt-updatepost-invoke-success-error-during-apt-ge)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04, apt-get stucked, fetched for 2 minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814797/ubuntu-16-04-apt-get-stucked-fetched-for-2-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

check out [this](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/issues/67#issuecomment-1167625874) issue on the Cubic GitHub page, it seems that the issue is when trying to edit Ubuntu 22.04 (newer) ISO image from an Ubuntu 18.04(older) host, you did not mention what OS you are running and what ISO image you are trying to edit.

A workaround is to try editing the OS through a Virtual Machine running a newer version of Ubuntu.