# I want to install oracle-java8 on Linux but Ubuntu says: already the newest version

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, java, oracle

I was following `sudo apt-get update` to add the java 8 repo to apt-get

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Again update the apt-get repo

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install java 8

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

but I had a lot of errors, so I fixed  and reinstalled them, but now it shows this image:

[image: screenshot from running apt]

```
ho@jhost:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

so I want to know java version is 8

```
ho@jhost:~$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

I need a solution to install oracle-java8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get Java to update from Java 7 to Java 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995831/cant-get-java-to-update-from-java-7-to-java-8)

Answer (score 2):

You can select the system wide java default executable via [update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-alternatives.8.html). Run the `update-alternatives` command with `--list` option to see the currently installed alternatives:

```
$ update-alternatives --list java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
...
```

Than change the default to your required java version with:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and follow the instruction on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all

I solved my problem

I notice to this part

```
No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2019-01-15 23:12:17--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.53.224.97
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.53.224.97|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2019-01-15 23:12:18--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 202.43.54.193, 2600:1417:e:285::366, 2600:1417:e:287::366
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|202.43.54.193|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547622858_9fc82e1ca238e15632f057856bbea8e9 [following]
--2019-01-15 23:12:18--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547622858_9fc82e1ca238e15632f057856bbea8e9
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.53.224.97|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547622858_9fc82e1ca238e15632f057856bbea8e9 [following]
--2019-01-15 23:12:18--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1547622858_9fc82e1ca238e15632f057856bbea8e9
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.53.224.97|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-01-15 23:12:19 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ho@jhost:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So I think it have to problem with URL path, java8 release version and sha256.

```
ho@jhost:~/Downloads$ sha256sum jdk-8u202-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Find sha256 of tar.gz file,

```
ho@jhost:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="9a5c32411a6a06e22b69c495b7975034409fa1652d03aeb8eb5b6f59fd4594e0"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

oracle-java8-installer pointed 8u191 version. so changed several things.

```
ho@jhost:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|JAVA_VERSION=8u202|' oracle-java8-installer.*
ho@jhost:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_202|' oracle-java8-installer.*
ho@jhost:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|PARTNER_URL=https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u202-b08/1961070e4c9b4e26a04e7f5a083f551e/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

And then,

```
ho@jhost:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Oracle JDK 8 installed

```
#####Important########
To set Oracle JDK8 as default, install the "oracle-java8-set-default" package.
E.g.: sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
On Ubuntu systems, oracle-java8-set-default is most probably installed
automatically with this package.
######################
```

I did it! thanks all again.