# can't install oracle-java8-installer (installer script out of date)

Tags: java, ppa, oracle

because, as far as I can tell, the installer in the webupd8 ppa is still trying to fetch update 191, but the earliest update Oracle has available is now 201.

There doesn't seem to be an issue tracker for webupd8; is there a workaround or way to direct the installer script to the newer version?

Comment: If you're trying to install java 8, try the openjdk-8-jdk package

Comment: I'm trying to install oracle's java 8, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing here, need oracle java 8 specifically.
Here's something related, trying it out now.
[I want to install oracle-java8 on Linux but Ubuntu says: already the newest version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110161/i-want-to-install-oracle-java8-on-linux-but-ubuntu-says-already-the-newest-vers)