# Can't install or remove using apt/dpkg due to broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, 17.10, dpkg, dependencies

Ubuntu 17.10

I did a `sudo apt-get upgrade`. then I tried install software-properties-common the next thing was that mysql-server-5.7 was making errors, so I tried to reinstall it, and now everything I'm trying to do has errors like:

```
root@rtcserver:~# apt install software-properties-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.27) but 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libnss3 : Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.12) but it is not going to be installed
 librados2 : Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not going to be installed
 software-properties-common : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.24.32.1) but 0.96.24.17 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

when I run `dpkg --configure -a`

```
root@rtcserver:~# dpkg --configure -aProcessing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up mssql-server (14.0.3023.8-5) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mssql-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.98ubuntu1.1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpam0g:amd64 (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu3.1) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
  Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mssql-server
 unattended-upgrades
 libpam0g:amd64
 libpam-systemd:amd64
```

and when I try to `dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libnss3 librados2`

```
root@rtcserver:~# dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libnss3 librados2 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc6-dev:amd64:
 zlib1g-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 libexpat1-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 libstdc++-7-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6).
 build-essential depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 libpcre3-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev.
 libtool depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 zlib1g-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 libexpat1-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 build-essential depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.
 libtool depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libnss3:amd64:
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.17.1).
 liboauth0:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~).
 ca-certificates-java depends on libnss3 (>= 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu3~).

dpkg: error processing package libnss3:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of librados2:
 libcephfs2 depends on librados2 (>= 12.0.3).

dpkg: error processing package librados2 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc-dev-bin:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc-dev-bin (= 2.27-3ubuntu1); however:
  Package libc-dev-bin is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package libc-dev-bin (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-dev:amd64
 libnss3:amd64
 librados2
 libc-dev-bin
```

when I try `apt --fix-broken install`

```
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("C.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 127695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The thing is I have unmet dependencies, which I cannot install, and they seems to be needed for every install I make.
Is there any way to fix this?

This is also a remote server which I don't have access to reboot.

EDIT: 
it's seems i'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and not 17.04

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 was released in 2017.April (hence 17.04) with 9 months of supported life which ended 2018-Jan-13.  It's now well past EOL, and default repos are no longer in archive.ubuntu.com (as occurs with EOL releases; they get moved to old-releases).  You should release-upgrade to 17.10 or move to 18.04.  (*Also 17.04 is now **off-topic** due to EOL status on this site, unless its related to moving to a supported version of Ubuntu*) Stick to LTS (long-term support) releases if you need a longer supported life.

Comment: Possible **off-topic** due to 17.04 being EOL.  Also **Possible duplicate of** https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: I tried upgrading to 18.04, but even that fails.

Comment: It's clear from the error messages that you have multiple minor problems with your system. Since 17.04 is no longer supported here, we gently suggest that you backup your data and clean-install 18.04. Tip: In the future, stay away from non-Ubuntu sources if you are unskilled at resolving dependencies. Avoid using any apt `--force` flag unless you really know what you are doing. And never let problems fester - diagnose and fix them immediately.

Comment: @user535733 my most urgent problem is this: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` ...slightly different than the dpkg command you tried already

Answer (score -2):

For some reason, this worked:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

as I have found in this post:

https://askubuntu.com/a/353423/826990

Comment: Congratulations - you may (or may not) have just broken your system quite horribly. Future readers - DON'T DO IT.

Comment: @user535733 what's the proper whay around this then?

Comment: Use the command:
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat

Check the PID and then:
sudo kill PID


/n the solution has been provided in trhe link from which you took your answer from.