# apt-get doesn't work correctly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I interrupted an installation, and now apt and apt-get don't work with any arguments. I always get the same error:

```
E: dpkg execution was interrupted, you must manually run "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to correct the problem.
```

EDIT :
I have tried to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it only did

```
Setting up cento (1.5.181022-373) ...
Making the /var/log/cento directory...
(Re)Starting cento...
^Cdpkg: error processing package cento (--configure):
 installed cento package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Setting up ntopng (3.7.181022-5357) ...
Rebuilding ld cache...
(Re)Starting ntopng...
^Cdpkg: error processing package ntopng (--configure):
 installed ntopng package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Setting up pfring-dkms (7.3.0) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package pfring-dkms (--configure):
 installed pfring-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cento
 ntopng
 pfring-dkms
```

EDIT 2:
I have tried `sudo apt install --reinstall cento` and this is the exit:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for cento:amd64
```

EDIT 3:
I have made s`udo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`

```
                     USUARIO        ORDEN DE ACCESO PID
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root       2845 F.... frontend
```

Then I made `sudo kill 2845`(I do not get an answer)
Then I made `sudo kill -9 2845`

```
kill: (2845): No such process
```

Then I tried `sudo apt autoremove`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up cento (1.5.181022-373) ...
Making the /var/log/cento directory...
(Re)Starting cento...

Progress: [  0%] [.............................................................]
```

And it stops there and doesn't do any more

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as suggested in the error?

Comment: Look up that error. Easy fix, you caused it when you CTRL+C. Don't let it distract from your current problem. Edit your question instead of putting information in comments. What is 'cento'?

Comment: Please also prepend `LC_ALL=C` to your commands so they produce English text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution to this locking problem is detailed in the [wiki](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/DebuggingInstallationIssues):

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Will show you what process is holding the lock:

```
USER        PID         ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
root      18210 F.... dpkg-preconfigu
```

Then you simply need to note down the PID and kill it like so:

```
sudo kill PID 
sudo kill -9 PID  # if the first doesn't work
```

Answered originally by [Sayed Jalil Hassan](https://askubuntu.com/a/380701/884818)

Comment: I edited the question with the result and I have not solve it

Comment: @lujoselu ``sudo dpkg --configure -a`` after this, No answer means you have successfully killed the program. Also tell us the program that was accessing that file.

Comment: I have already solved thank you. Also I do not know how to mark a question as answered