# How do I fix apt-get and apt-update/upgrade after my computer shut down during an installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was running `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade -y` and midway through the installation my computer ran out of battery and shut down abruptly. Side note - I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10.

Now when I run `sudo apt upgrade` I'm getting errors that I can't figure out how to work around. Here's what I get:

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd (= 229-4ubuntu21.6) but 229-4ubuntu21.4 is installed
systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.4) but 229-4ubuntu21.6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I try that and here's what I get:

```
~$ sudo apt upgrade -y -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
ubuntu-advantage-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
apt-transport-https cloud-init curl distro-info-data dpkg-dev friendly-recovery gettext-base kmod libasprintf0v5 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdpkg-perl libgs9 libgs9-common libkmod2 libmspack0 libpam-systemd libsystemd0 libudev1
linux-libc-dev openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server python3-cryptography python3-requests python3-update-manager systemd systemd-sysv tzdata ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard udev update-manager-core yarn
34 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,245 kB/17.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 531 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpam-systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [115 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [54.1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 udev amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [993 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libsystemd0 amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [204 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 systemd amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [3,775 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 systemd-sysv amd64 229-4ubuntu21.8 [11.6 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libasprintf0v5 amd64 0.19.7-2ubuntu3.1 [6,568 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 gettext-base amd64 0.19.7-2ubuntu3.1 [48.0 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libmspack0 amd64 0.5-1ubuntu0.16.04.3 [37.4 kB]
Fetched 5,245 kB in 15s (333 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 60877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpam-systemd:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.8) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
(Reading database ... 60877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../udev_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udev (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libsystemd0_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libsystemd0:amd64 (229-4ubuntu21.8) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
(Reading database ... 60877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
unable to make backup symlink for './lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                        Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` and got:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for andre:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
systemd
Suggested packages:
systemd-ui systemd-container
The following packages will be upgraded:
systemd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,775 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 60877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (229-4ubuntu21.8) over (229-4ubuntu21.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
unable to make backup symlink for './lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                        Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this and get my package manager back to a healthy state?

Comment: have you tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Yeah, I'll update my original post with the output - short version it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to first clean with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

then try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

or/and

```
sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

Comment: When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get this error:

Comment: Setting up kmod (22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
 libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on systemd (= 229-4ubuntu21.8); however:
  Package systemd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam-systemd:amd64

Comment: I think you should have a look at this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file `/var/cache/apt/archives/systemd_229-4ubuntu21.8_amd64.deb` is corrupted.

While trying to install systemd, The package manager assumes that there is already a cached deb file, so just delete it and run `sudo apt-get -f install` again.

Comment: Really thought that would work but it looks like I get the same error. It creates the file again.

Answer (score 0):

On my normal Ubuntu 18.10 that file you have missing does appear however its just a symlink as per :

```
ls -la /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov  9 03:15 /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
```

so to give yourself such a file issue

```
sudo ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service
```

then reissue your

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is just a hunch however that missing symlink may be part of a larger issue ... dunno until you try

Just to give some context here is my entire /lib/systemd/system/

```
scott@berghia /lib/systemd/system $ ls -la /lib/systemd/system/
total 1116
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 36864 Nov 12 14:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:46 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   631 Nov  3  2016 accounts-daemon.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   115 Feb  9  2016 acpid.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234 Apr  8  2016 acpid.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   115 Feb  9  2016 acpid.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   510 Apr 14  2016 alsa-restore.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   483 Apr 14  2016 alsa-state.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Apr 14  2016 alsa-utils.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   283 Dec 28  2014 anacron-resume.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   183 Dec 28  2014 anacron.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   142 Mar 31  2016 apport-forward@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   246 May 24 11:15 apport-forward.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   225 Oct  9 06:36 apt-daily.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   156 Oct  9 06:36 apt-daily.timer
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   238 Oct  9 06:36 apt-daily-upgrade.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184 Oct  9 06:36 apt-daily-upgrade.timer
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    14 Nov  9 03:15 autovt@.service -> getty@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1044 Apr 17  2018 avahi-daemon.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   874 Apr 17  2018 avahi-daemon.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   879 Nov  9 03:15 basic.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 28  2018 basic.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1159 Feb 22  2016 binfmt-support.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   384 Jan 18  2018 bluetooth.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   379 Nov  9 03:15 bluetooth.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 bootlogd.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 bootlogs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 bootmisc.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   545 Apr 27  2016 brltty.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   429 Apr 27  2016 brltty-udev.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   358 Nov  9 03:15 busnames.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Dec 15  2016 busnames.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   263 Sep 14  2015 cgmanager.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   222 Sep 14  2015 cgproxy.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 checkfs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 checkroot-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 checkroot.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   298 Nov  6  2015 colord.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   770 Nov  9 03:15 console-getty.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   288 Jun 16  2016 console-setup.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   742 Nov  9 03:15 console-shell.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   486 Nov  5 15:04 containerd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   791 Nov  9 03:15 container-getty@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   251 Apr  5  2016 cron.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 cryptdisks-early.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 cryptdisks.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   394 Nov  9 03:15 cryptsetup-pre.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   366 Nov  9 03:15 cryptsetup.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    13 Nov  9 03:15 ctrl-alt-del.target -> reboot.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234 May  7  2018 cups-browsed.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   142 Jun 22 14:30 cups.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   175 Jun 22 14:30 cups.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   116 Jun 22 14:30 cups.socket
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service -> systemd-hostnamed.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    23 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service -> systemd-localed.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service -> systemd-logind.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service -> systemd-networkd.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    24 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service -> systemd-resolved.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25 Nov  9 03:15 dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service -> systemd-timedated.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   491 Jan 12  2017 dbus.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   106 Jan 12  2017 dbus.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1010 Nov  9 03:15 debug-shell.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Nov  9 03:15 default.target -> graphical.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   670 Nov  9 03:15 dev-hugepages.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   624 Nov  9 03:15 dev-mqueue.mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 10  2016 display-manager.service.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   428 Oct 23  2015 dns-clean.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   924 Jul 12 09:39 dnsmasq.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1599 Nov  6 19:51 docker.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1009 Nov  9 03:15 emergency.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   431 Nov  9 03:15 emergency.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   501 Nov  9 03:15 exit.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   364 Aug  2  2015 fail2ban.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   134 Aug 20  2016 failsafe-graphical.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   232 Aug 20  2016 failsafe-x.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   440 Nov  9 03:15 final.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   618 Oct  2 14:43 friendly-recovery.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   172 Oct  2 14:43 friendly-recovery.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 fuse.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   117 Jan 18  2018 fwupdate-cleanup.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1536 Nov  9 03:15 getty@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   342 Nov  7 19:01 getty-static.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   460 Nov  9 03:15 getty.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 getty.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   239 Mar 10  2017 gpu-manager.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   558 Nov  9 03:15 graphical.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 graphical.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 halt.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   487 Nov  9 03:15 halt.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 22 12:44 halt.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   447 Nov  9 03:15 hibernate.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 hostname.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 hwclock.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   468 Nov  9 03:15 hybrid-sleep.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   497 Nov 30  2016 ifup@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   133 Feb 28  2017 iio-sensor-proxy.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   630 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-cleanup.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   553 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-fs.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   790 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-parse-etc.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   526 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-root-fs.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   640 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-switch-root.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   691 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-switch-root.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 22 12:44 initrd-switch-root.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   671 Nov  9 03:15 initrd.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   664 Nov  9 03:15 initrd-udevadm-cleanup-db.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   201 Jun  1  2014 ipmievd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   376 Mar 10  2016 kerneloops.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   501 Nov  9 03:15 kexec.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 22 12:44 kexec.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   285 Jun 16  2016 keyboard-setup.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 killprocs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    28 Nov  9 03:15 kmod.service -> systemd-modules-load.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   677 Nov  9 03:15 kmod-static-nodes.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   506 Mar 31  2017 lightdm.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234 Aug 17  2014 lighttpd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   199 Apr  5  2014 lm-sensors.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   395 Nov  9 03:15 local-fs-pre.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   507 Nov  9 03:15 local-fs.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 local-fs.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   405 Nov  9 03:15 machine.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   473 Nov  9 03:15 mail-transport-agent.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   268 Jan 24  2018 ModemManager.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    28 Nov  9 03:15 module-init-tools.service -> systemd-modules-load.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 motd.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountall-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountall.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountdevsubfs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountkernfs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountnfs-bootclean.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 mountnfs.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   492 Nov  9 03:15 multi-user.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 multi-user.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   735 Nov 30  2016 networking.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   364 Nov  2 16:15 NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 Nov  2 16:15 network-manager.service -> NetworkManager.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   857 Nov  2 16:15 NetworkManager.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   303 Nov  2 16:15 NetworkManager-wait-online.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   464 Nov  9 03:15 network-online.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   461 Nov  9 03:15 network-pre.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   480 Nov  9 03:15 network.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   514 Nov  9 03:15 nss-lookup.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   473 Nov  9 03:15 nss-user-lookup.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   354 Nov  9 03:15 paths.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   412 May  9  2018 plymouth-halt.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   426 May  9  2018 plymouth-kexec.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 May  9  2018 plymouth-log.service -> plymouth-read-write.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   421 May  9  2018 plymouth-poweroff.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   194 May  9  2018 plymouth-quit.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   200 May  9  2018 plymouth-quit-wait.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   244 May  9  2018 plymouth-read-write.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   416 May  9  2018 plymouth-reboot.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 May  9  2018 plymouth.service -> plymouth-quit.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   532 May  9  2018 plymouth-start.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   291 May  9  2018 plymouth-switch-root.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182 Jan 14  2016 polkitd.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    15 Nov 11  2015 portmap.service -> rpcbind.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   337 Jul 16 12:22 postgresql.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1356 Jul 16 12:22 postgresql@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   552 Nov  9 03:15 poweroff.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 poweroff.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   207 Jan 27  2016 pppd-dns.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   377 Nov  9 03:15 printer.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    22 Nov  9 03:15 procps.service -> systemd-sysctl.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   693 Nov  9 03:15 proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   603 Nov  9 03:15 proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   568 Nov  9 03:15 quotaon.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   612 Nov  9 03:15 rc-local.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Nov  9 03:15 rc.local.service -> rc-local.service
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 rc-local.service.d
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 rc.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 rcS.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 reboot.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   543 Nov  9 03:15 reboot.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 reboot.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   396 Nov  9 03:15 remote-fs-pre.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   482 Nov  9 03:15 remote-fs.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   978 Nov  9 03:15 rescue.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   486 Nov  9 03:15 rescue.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 rescue.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   420 Nov 29  2017 resolvconf.service
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 resolvconf.service.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 rmnologin.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   407 Nov 10  2015 rpcbind.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   128 Nov  5  2015 rpcbind.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   500 Nov  9 03:15 rpcbind.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   188 Feb 24  2014 rsync.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   290 Apr  5  2016 rsyslog.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1055 Oct 26  2015 rtkit-daemon.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    15 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    13 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 18  2016 runlevel1.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 18  2016 runlevel2.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 18  2016 runlevel3.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 18  2016 runlevel4.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Feb 18  2016 runlevel5.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    13 Nov  9 03:15 runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Mar 30  2017 saned.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   309 Apr 25  2015 saned@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   132 Dec 12  2014 saned.socket
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 sendsigs.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1038 Nov  9 03:15 serial-getty@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   269 Jan 31  2017 setvtrgb.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   402 Nov  9 03:15 shutdown.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   153 Nov  7 19:01 sigpwr-container-shutdown.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   362 Nov  9 03:15 sigpwr.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 sigpwr.target.wants
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 single.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   420 Nov  9 03:15 sleep.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   403 Nov  9 03:15 -.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   409 Nov  9 03:15 slices.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   380 Nov  9 03:15 smartcard.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   252 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.autoimport.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   320 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.core-fixup.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   172 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.failure.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   322 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.seeded.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   411 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   372 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.snap-repair.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   281 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.snap-repair.timer
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   281 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   503 Oct 25 06:00 snapd.system-shutdown.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   356 Nov  9 03:15 sockets.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:46 sockets.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   380 Nov  9 03:15 sound.target
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 stop-bootlogd.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 stop-bootlogd-single.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   441 Nov  9 03:15 suspend.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   353 Nov  9 03:15 swap.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   715 Nov  9 03:15 sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   518 Nov  9 03:15 sysinit.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:46 sysinit.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   719 Nov  9 03:15 sys-kernel-config.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   662 Nov  9 03:15 sys-kernel-debug.mount
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1235 Nov  9 03:15 syslog.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   646 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-ask-password-console.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   653 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-ask-password-console.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   490 May  9  2018 systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   467 May  9  2018 systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   574 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-ask-password-wall.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   681 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-ask-password-wall.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   724 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-backlight@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   959 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-binfmt.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   650 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-bootchart.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1024 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-bus-proxyd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   409 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-bus-proxyd.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   497 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-exit.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   551 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-fsckd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   540 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-fsckd.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   674 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-fsck-root.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   648 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-fsck@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   544 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-halt.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   631 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-hibernate-resume@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   501 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-hibernate.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   710 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-hostnamed.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   778 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-hwdb-update.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   519 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-hybrid-sleep.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   480 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-initctl.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   524 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-initctl.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   607 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-journald-audit.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1090 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1276 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-journald.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   842 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-journald.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   731 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-journal-flush.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   557 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-kexec.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   691 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-localed.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1179 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-logind.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   693 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-machine-id-commit.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   967 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-modules-load.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   175 Nov  7 19:01 systemd-networkd-resolvconf-update.path
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   715 Nov  7 19:01 systemd-networkd-resolvconf-update.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1277 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-networkd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   591 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-networkd.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   685 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   553 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-poweroff.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   614 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-quotacheck.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   717 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-random-seed.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   548 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-reboot.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   757 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-remount-fs.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   907 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-resolved.service
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 systemd-resolved.service.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   696 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-rfkill.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   617 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-rfkill.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   497 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-suspend.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   653 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-sysctl.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   655 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-timedated.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1032 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-timesyncd.service
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 systemd-timesyncd.service.d
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   598 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   450 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   703 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   683 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   578 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-udevd-control.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   570 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   825 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-udevd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   823 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-udev-settle.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   743 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-udev-trigger.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   757 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   754 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-update-utmp.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   573 Nov  9 03:15 systemd-user-sessions.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   436 Nov  9 03:15 system.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   585 Nov  9 03:15 system-update.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   254 Apr 18  2017 thermald.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   405 Nov  9 03:15 timers.target
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 12 14:45 timers.target.wants
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   395 Nov  9 03:15 time-sync.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   571 Mar  7  2016 udev-configure-printer@.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 Nov  9 03:15 udev.service -> systemd-udevd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   196 Apr  1  2016 udisks2.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   241 Mar  3  2015 ufw.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 umountfs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 umountnfs.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 umountroot.service -> /dev/null
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   417 Nov  9 03:15 umount.target
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   451 Jun 15  2016 upower.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    27 Nov  9 03:15 urandom.service -> systemd-random-seed.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   401 Feb 24  2015 ureadahead.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   250 Feb 24  2015 ureadahead-stop.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   242 Feb 24  2015 ureadahead-stop.timer
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   178 Oct  5  2015 usb_modeswitch@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   183 Jan  4  2016 usbmuxd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   528 Nov  9 03:15 user@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   392 Nov  9 03:15 user.slice
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   189 May 16 10:59 uuidd.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   126 May 16 10:59 uuidd.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   167 Mar  3  2016 wacom-inputattach@.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   253 Jul 27  2017 whoopsie.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   266 Aug  9 14:52 wpa_supplicant.service
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Nov  9 03:15 x11-common.service -> /dev/null
```

of course content of your above dir may differ however this might help you get into the ballpark ... obviously mucking about with systemd is performing a head-to-body transplant so YMMV

Comment: I tried this but when I ran `sudo ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service` I got:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service': File exists`

Comment: Try to remove and recreate the symlink. `sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service` then `sudo ln -s /dev/null /lib/systemd/system/checkroot-bootclean.service ` 
Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` and post the results in pastebin (give the link here).