# Have been getting this error while installing couple of packages in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install -f gnome-tweak-tool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-tweak-tool is already the newest version (3.28.1-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra libmspack0 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up acpi-call-dkms (1.1.0-4) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package acpi-call-dkms (--configure):
 installed acpi-call-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up tp-smapi-dkms (0.42-1ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package tp-smapi-dkms (--configure):
 installed tp-smapi-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
**Errors were encountered while processing:
 acpi-call-dkms
 tp-smapi-dkms**
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 acpi-call-dkms
 tp-smapi-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Hi Manas, what is the question here? Also, please don't just post a blob of text that you've copied from the terminal, please wrap it properly as a code block before pasting. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/2469559

Comment: when i am trying  to install "sudo apt-get install -f gnome-tweak-tool" getting the error : **Errors were encountered while processing:
 acpi-call-dkms
 tp-smapi-dkms**
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f RedShift 
Unable to install Redshift: Error while installing package: installed acpi-call-dkms package post installtion script subprocess return error exit status 1.

Comment: debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package tp-smapi-dkms (--configure):
 installed tp-smapi-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libavutil55:amd64 (7:3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (19.0.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libswresample2:amd64 (7:3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...

Comment: No one can read this stuff in comments, [edit] your question and add it there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)