# Apt-get not working on Linux 18.04.3 LTS - unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dpkg, dependencies

I have been trying to install packages using apt-get but it gives me a list of packages that have unmet dependencies. Also, if I try to install anything from the package manager it gives me an error again.

```
    Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'node-jstimezonedetect' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-buffer' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-localizer' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-stable-stringify' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-schema-traverse' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jszip-utils' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsv' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonstream' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-schema' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-js-cookie' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsesc' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-stringify-safe' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json3' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json5' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-parse-better-errors' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jscoverage' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-js-yaml' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jssip' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-loader' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonminify' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsprim' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonselect' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonfile' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonparse' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json2module' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jszip' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsonify' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jschardet' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-js-tokens' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-js-beautify' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-json-parse-helpfulerror' for regex 'node.js'
Note, selecting 'node-jsbn' for regex 'node.js'
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libedit2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libelf1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libexpat1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 libffi6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libglvnd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx-mesa0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-compute-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-encode-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
 libpciaccess0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libsensors4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not going to be installed
 libtinfo5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 libxau6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb-glx0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb-present0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb-sync1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxdamage1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxfixes3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libxshmfence1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not going to be installed
 libxxf86vm1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 node-js-beautify : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-config-chain (>= 1.1.5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-nopt (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 node-js-cookie : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-js-tokens : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-js-yaml : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: node-argparse (>= 1.0.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: node-esprima (>= 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsbn : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jschardet : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsesc : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-buffer : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-loader : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-localizer : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-parse-better-errors : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-parse-helpfulerror : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                                Depends: node-jju (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-schema : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-schema-traverse : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-stable-stringify : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json-stringify-safe : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json2module : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: node-rw (>= 1.3.2) but it is not going to be installed
 node-json3 : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-json5 : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonfile : Depends: nodejs (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 4.1.6) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonify : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonminify : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonparse : Depends: nodejs (>= 4.7) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonselect : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libjs-jquery but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsonstream : Depends: nodejs (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: node-through (>= 2.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: node-through (< 3) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsprim : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: node-assert-plus (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: node-extsprintf (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: node-verror (>= 1.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jssip : Depends: node-websocket but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-rtcninja but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-util but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-sdp-transform but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-events but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-debug but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjs-jssip (= 0.6.34-5) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: javascript-common but it is not going to be installed
 node-jstimezonedetect : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libjs-jstimezonedetect (= 1.0.6-1)
                         Recommends: javascript-common but it is not going to be installed
 node-jsv : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 node-jszip : Depends: nodejs (>= 2.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-es6-promise (>= 3.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-lie (>= 3.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-core-js (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: node-pako (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 node-jszip-utils : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run the command apt --fix-broken install it gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib linux-headers-4.15.0-66 linux-headers-4.15.0-66-generic linux-image-4.15.0-66-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-66-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-66-generic python-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
66 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,551 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 210334 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have been trying to fix this solution since three days and have visited every solution provided on stack overflow and other sites but none of them solved my problem.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: What was the last thing you did before this started happening?

Comment: I am not sure. I was trying to connect an external monitor and it was not working. I tried installing different packages and ended up with this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t). Good job writing the question. You included the key information, and you formatted properly. Well done!

Comment: Thank you! I installed linux again on my laptop as it was becoming very frustrating. Thanks again!