# Package System is broken

Tags: package-management, dpkg, update-manager, 19.10

I currently have Ubuntu 19.10. I don't how my package system broke. I did not install anything new in the last week, as far as my memory goes. But suddenly an error started showing up. Now, I cannot even update my system. Please help if you can. I have tried many commands I could look up online, but none of them worked. The dpkg folder always returned an error code 1. Below are the screenshots for reference.

[image: Software Updater Prompt]

[image: Terminal message]

[image: The package manager shows the latest version is installed]

The package manager shows the latest version is installed
but..

[image]
the terminal shows that a previous version is installed.

Comment: Please provide text, and not pictures of text.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libc6-dbg shows *2.30-0ubuntu2.1* is the latest for eoan not *2.30-0ubuntu2* so either your sources list is out of date (ie. you need to `sudo apt update`) OR you're using an outdated mirror or have other like issue (ie. use `apt-cache policy` to explore)

Comment: I ran into a similar vague issue with libc6 on two systems and I used `aptitude` not `apt` or `apt-get` to attempt the installation/upgrade and it resolved the issue. YMMV

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more simple one command

I just did:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

After I run the `sudo apt-get install` and (I was installing curl ) and it worked restored the db manual pages.