# Update error: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: upgrade, updates, dpkg

While trying to update and upgrade I get an error, I've tried the following methods to solve it but didn't work:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt remove 

sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

Maybe this is the couse why I can't boot the last version of ubuntu and I have  to choos the previous one.

Packages with error:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2-common
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04
 grub-pc
 libgconf-2-4:amd64
 linux-base
 megax
 cups
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 network-manager
 cups-bsd
 mercurial
 unattended-upgrades
 linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic
 gconf-service-backend
 discord
 ubuntu-standard
 linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic
 network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
 gconf-service
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There are many standard ubuntu packages, I don't know which is the problem. 
My current version of ubuntu is 18.04.4

Extra information, the dpkg errors:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-4ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 installed gconf2-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 (2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 installed xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.15) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf-2-4:amd64:
 libgconf-2-4:amd64 depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf-2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-base (4.5ubuntu1.1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package linux-base (--configure):
 installed linux-base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                         dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of megax:
 megax depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package megax (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cups (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 installed cups package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
 network-manager depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cups-bsd (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
 installed cups-bsd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up mercurial (4.5.3-1ubuntu2.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mercurial (--configure):
 installed mercurial package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.14) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic:
 linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic depends on linux-base (>= 4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package linux-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service-backend:
 gconf-service-backend depends on libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf-service-backend depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service-backend (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                         dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package discord (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-standard:
 ubuntu-standard depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-standard (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic:
 linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic depends on linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic is not configured yet.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-51-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:
 network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu depends on network-manager (>= 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package network-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service:
 gconf-service depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-4ubuntu1); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic; however:
  Package linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (= 5.3.0.51.104); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-generic-hwe-18.04; however:
  Package linux-generic-hwe-18.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
```

Send help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)