# Dualboot Windows/Ubuntu - Impossible to uninstall VirtualBox

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, apt, virtualbox, windows

I have on my computer Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS in dual boot with Grub. EFI and Secure boot are enabled in BIOS.

I would like to uninstall Virtualbox in order to install a new version (>6.1) having no issues with my Linux kernel but I'm not able to do it.
Thus, when I run `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-6.0`, I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-6.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 228 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 210501 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-6.0 (6.0.22-137980~Ubuntu~bionic) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.0 (--remove):
 installed virtualbox-6.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And when I do `fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`, I don't see any processus, nothing.

Would you know why is there this error exactly please ? And how to fix it so that I can reinstall VirtualBox 6.1 ? If possible, without desactivating secure boot and EFI.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: Can you please post the outputs of **dmseg** related to VBox ?

Comment: @user535733 I think the problem is [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/virtualbox-6010-adds-uefi-secure-boot.html) hence the error **vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed**

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, but it is what I actually wanted to say at the end of my post.

Comment: @Pilot6 The aim was exactly to not disable it, otherwise I would have done it earlier. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Thanks for your help. I've finally found a solution that has nothing to do with that. Below the solution.

Comment: My solution to fix it : 
My disk space sda had no space left. So I had to remove files. Then I used the command "fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat" to kill all blocking processus. And then I deleted VirtualBox.