# Cannot install required libraries for Android Studio

Tags: dpkg, android-studio

```
dr_insult@futcap:~$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
[sudo] password for dr_insult: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lib32z1 is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1).
libbz2-1.0:i386 is already the newest version (1.0.8-2).
libstdc++6:i386 is already the newest version (10-20200411-0ubuntu1).
libncurses5:i386 is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,570 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 199059 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am trying to install Android Studio. Hence I was following the instructions on it's website. The following command had been given there, but dpkg keeps returning an error. I have been facing similar errors while updating too. Is there some problem with my system. Please help.

I have already tried the command

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

and then kill the process.

It works on a temporary basis. The problem keeps coming back. Please suggest a permanent solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: It does in a way. I have to always use that command to kill the process using config.dat. Please share a permanent solution on why is is happening.

Comment: What does it give for the command using the file?

Comment: I think the process id vaires (but I am not sure). But "frontend" is always there in the p name.

Comment: Before you unnecessarily disable auto updates whats the output of `ps -p PID -o user,comm,args` where PID is the process with the lock on the file?