# Failed install of VirtualBox unable to uninstall, purge, or reinstall

Tags: virtualbox, uninstall

I'm trying to make the switch from Windows to GNU/linux. So far, I've installed Ubuntu, messed around with the command line a bit, and tried to install VirtualBox so I can run Windows 10 in a container and use it only for programs I can't run on linux or which run poorly on linux.

I've hit a snag.  I tried to install VirtualBox but ran into some trouble.  The install did not go successfully.  Now I'm trying to remove VirtualBox via this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
```

The result is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up virtualbox-6.0 (6.0.24-139119~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.0 (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-6.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried the clean, remove, reinstall commands. No dice. Any help? Total noob here.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/a/380701/453950) should get you sorted. This question has been asked in all sorts of formats over the years.

Comment: If you use ``sudo apt-get update`` do you still get the error saying that "../config.dat is locked by another process" ?

Comment: Thanks, KGIII.  That link did get me sorted.  Sorry if I've asked a common question.  I did some searching but couldn't quite get my search terms right I guess. Thanks again.