# Cannot fully remove Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded the latest version of Virtualbox from Oracle website and installed it on my Ubuntu 18.04. It all went well until at the end when I had a few warnings about broken packages etc. Didn't get round to using it even though it launched fine and was ready to go. Later on I updated the system and I needed to reboot. Bootloader gave me three new options none of which made any sense to me. I ignored them and clicked on the fourth option of "continue to boot". A red notification warning appeared at the top right of the screen. Guessing it was all related to Virtualbox I deleted/removed/purged it. The warning disappeared. Now everytime I want to do a system update it says it wants to install Virtualbox -- it says it is already downloaded!

[image]

The only thing related to Virtualbox I can find is:

```
$ which virtualbox
/usr/bin/virtualbox
```

and

```
$ ps -ef | grep vbox
elmclose   12101 10341  0 15:48 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto vbox
```

(vbox is in red)
cannot kill this process -- it says there is no process to kill

Has something crept into my BIOS? how can I get rid of every trace of Virtualbox from my system?

Comment: Your `ps -ef` statement is just returning your grep process; there's no Virtualbox running. What does `aptitude search virtualbox | grep ^i` return?

Comment: $ aptitude search virtualbox | grep ^i
i A unity-scope-virtualbox - VirtualBox scope for Unity
i  virtualbox-6.1 - Oracle VM VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Running this should purge the remnants of Virtualbox:

```
sudo apt purge unity-scope-virtualbox virtualbox-6.1
```

Comment: this is part of what I get when I run that command:debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.1 (--remove):
 installed virtualbox-6.1 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

Comment: And this is how it finished:There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: This should help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t