# apt does not work

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg

I try to use `sudo apt upgrade`
this is the output:

```
lnee@fallback:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for lnee: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up ca-certificates (20201027ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 installed ca-certificates package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up anbox-modules-dkms (13) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package anbox-modules-dkms (--configure):
 installed anbox-modules-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed | grub-efi-arm64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
  Package grub-efi-arm64-signed is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates
 grub-efi-amd64
 anbox-modules-dkms
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
lnee@fallback:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: i try that then sudo apt upgrade this is what i got Configuring grub-efi-amd64 GRUB failed to install to the following devices:  /dev/sda2 Do you want to continue anyway? If you do, your computer may not start up properly.  Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue?   <Yes>                           <No>

Answer (score 0):

(note found this later this does not work the error was still there)
So I first ran the command

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

and I got this

> ```
> /var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
> USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
> root      40970 F.... frontend
> ```

and so i got the process id (`40970`) and killed it
`sudo kill 40970` (insert the process id).

Then I did `sudo apt upgrade`

and then I got this

> ```
> Configuring grub-efi-amd64 GRUB failed to install to the following devices: /dev/sda2  
> Do you want to continue anyway?  
> If you do, your computer may not start up properly.  
> Writing GRUB to boot device failed - continue? <Yes> <No>
> ```

So I pressed `<No>`, then `<Ok>` and I think it's fixed.

Comment: the error is still there