# I cannot uninstall Virtualbox

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dpkg, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall VirtualBox out of my Ubuntu 20.04 because it either didn't install correctly or didn't work correctly. But when I run remove and purge cmds into the terminal, it acts like Vbox isn't installed while I can search loads of Vbox files and even can launch the app itself and it works fine. So, it's installed in the system. But the the terminals cmds are unable to locate it correctly? I'll post the uninstalltion cmds that I used

```
anjug@anjug-vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo apt purge virtualbox
[sudo] password for anjug: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm10 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

anjug@anjug-vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libllvm10 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 264 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 227277 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic (5.4.0-58.64) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
```

Comment: Is this the complete output? Also, please run `lsof | grep /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` to check which process is blocking dpkg.

Comment: How did you install VirtualBox? Via apt, dpkg, or tarfile?

Comment: .deb file from the official site.

Comment: Yes, that is the complete output @BulletBob That cmd gives no output at all. It looks like I'm going to have to manually delete the vbox folders because there is no way to uninstall it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)