# Can't Unistall Virtualbox

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I want to uninstall Virtualbox. So, this command

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-6.1
```

And I got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common libappindicator1 libc++1
  libc++1-10 libc++abi1-10 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libgconf-2-4 libpython2-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libqt5opengl5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
  libsdl1.2debian python-is-python2 python2 python2-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox-6.1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 216 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-samyak-taml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-guru' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sahadeva' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'alsa-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-orya' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-orya' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-pagul' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-taml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgdata-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gujr' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-mlym' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-knda' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-samyak-gujr' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-nakula' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-samyak-mlym' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-navilu' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-taml-classical' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-telu' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gargi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gubbi' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-deva' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ftp' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-dejavu-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-samyak-deva' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-droid-fallback' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'iw' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsamplerate0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-mlym' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tibetan-machine' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 198279 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.1 (--remove):
 installed virtualbox-6.1 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.1
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
Error: Timeout was reached
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove extension pack and it doesn't work. Please Sir, help me.

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove virtualbox-6.1 Try this command.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   the only clear detail in your paste is an off-topic *eoan* package.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.

Comment: sorry sir, it didn't work.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)