# Software Updater doesn't update and returns : Package Operation Failed

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, dpkg, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

[image: Ubuntu version]

When I try to update with the Software Updater it returns this error:

[image: Package Operation Failed]

I have tried everything that I found here and still no results, the
above error is repeated every time.

When I try to update from the terminal with this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

it returns:

```
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam0g:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpam0g:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: terminal output]

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, but without solving this, it seems that I can't.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: Seems that there is another process running.

Comment: Please examine [https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys this link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t  from Charles Green helped me resolve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)