# Trying to Install Docker but I get a processing error libpam0g:amd64

Tags: apt, dpkg, docker

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install \
apt-transport-https \
ca-certificates \
curl \
gnupg \
lsb-release
```

I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (11.1.0ubuntu2).
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20210119~20.04.1).
curl is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.5).
gnupg is already the newest version (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1).
The following packages will be upgraded:
apt-transport-https
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 150 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,680 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 2.0.6 [4,680 B]
Fetched 4,680 B in 1s (7,853 B/s)               
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libpam0g:amd64 (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
installed libpam0g:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
libpam0g:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried reinstalling libpam0g:amd64 but I still get the same error

EDIT:

It's not just Docker, I can't install any package (not even curl) I get the same error message regarding libpam0g:amd64

Comment: see this it may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t

Comment: Thank you! I can finally install Docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)