# Problem with dpkg E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg

Hi maybe someone can help me solve my problem, I have a problem with dpkg

To fix the problem should I remove one by one the each of package mentioned in the output?

I have tried to run command
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f

And I always get the same error message.

Whole output

```
    sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp2-2:amd64:
 libfreerdp2-2:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwinpr2-2:amd64:
 libwinpr2-2:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libwinpr2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic:
 linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.4.2~20.04.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                       debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssl:
 openssl depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openssl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-legacy (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-legacy (--configure):
 installed xserver-xorg-legacy package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64:
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libfreerdp2-2 (>= 2.1.0+dfsg1); however:
  Package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.1.0+dfsg1); however:
  Package libwinpr2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wget:
 wget depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: error processing package wget (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.11.0.41.45~20.04.19); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for ca-certificates:
 ca-certificates depends on openssl (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package openssl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.1:amd64
 libfreerdp2-2:amd64
 libwinpr2-2:amd64
 linux-headers-5.11.0-41-generic
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
 openssl
 xserver-xorg-legacy
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64
 wget
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
 ca-certificates
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Enough place on your filesystems? Please [edit] your question and show `df -h;df -i`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)