# Was trying to install chrome and ran into this error

Tags: apt, dpkg, google-chrome

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) but  2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
 libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2)
              Recommends: update-motd but it is not installed
   mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (=   8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) 
   but 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 is installed
   E: Unmet dependencies.
   Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> Then tried to run apt --fix-broken install and ran into error again.

```
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   libfwupdplugin1 libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 linux-headers-5.4.0-73
   linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic
   linux-modules-5.4.0-73-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-73-generic
   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
   The following additional packages will be installed:
   libc6 libc6:i386 libpam-modules mysql-server-8.0 virtualbox-dkms
   Suggested packages:
    glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 mailx tinyca
   Recommended packages:
   update-motd virtualbox
   The following packages will be upgraded:
   libc6 libc6:i386 libpam-modules mysql-server-8.0 virtualbox-dkms
  5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
  278 not fully installed or removed.
  Need to get 0 B/7,529 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 46.1 kB disk space will be freed.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is  locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  (Reading database ... 475599 files and directories currently     installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb ...
   De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
   debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is  locked by another p
   rocess: Resource temporarily unavailable
   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives /libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd
       64.deb (--unpack):
   new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess       returned error exit 
   status 1
   Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_i386.deb ...
   De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
   debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another p
   rocess: Resource temporarily unavailable
   dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_i38
   6.deb (--unpack):
   new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_amd64.deb
   /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.9_i386.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

> Tried sudo apt autoremove

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) but      2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
    libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
    libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.2)
       Recommends: update-motd but it is not installed
      mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (=     8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) but 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 is installed
      E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> Got the same error so, tried running sudo dpkg --configure -a and got this

```
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-8.0:
    mysql-server-8.0 depends on mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2);      however:
    Version of mysql-server-core-8.0 on system is 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3.

    dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up linux-base (4.5ubuntu3.7) ...
   debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another    process: Resource temporarily unavailable
   dpkg: error processing package linux-base (--configure):
   installed linux-base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit  status 1
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
   initramfs-tools depends on linux-base; however:
   Package linux-base is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   Setting up cups-bsd (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.2) ...
   debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another   process: Resource temporarily unavailable
   dpkg: error processing package cups-bsd (--configure):
   installed cups-bsd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
  Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13) ...
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another   process: Resource temporarily unavailable
 dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libssl1.1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
 Setting up libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13) ...
 debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another  process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package libssl1.1:i386 (--configure):
installed libssl1.1:i386 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp2-2:amd64:
 libfreerdp2-2:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
 Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpython3.8-dbg:amd64:
 libpython3.8-dbg:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
 Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libpython3.8-dbg:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsasl2-modules:amd64:
 libsasl2-modules:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
 Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsasl2-modules:i386:
 libsasl2-modules:i386 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
 Package libssl1.1:i386 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libsasl2-modules:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Setting up rsyslog (8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.3) ...
 The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
 The user `syslog' is already a member of `tty'.
 debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process:       Resource temporarily unavailable
 dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 installed rsyslog package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
 Setting up ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ...
 debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
 dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 installed ufw package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-cli:
 php7.4-cli depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
 Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package php7.4-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up samba-common (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2) ...
 debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another   process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package samba-common (--configure):
  installed samba-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error   exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kmod:
  kmod depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package kmod (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apache2-bin:
  apache2-bin depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package apache2-bin (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up locales (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another   process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package locales (--configure):
  installed locales package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwinpr2-2:amd64:
  libwinpr2-2:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
   Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package libwinpr2-2:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt5network5:amd64:
  libqt5network5:amd64 depends on libssl1.1; however:
   Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libqt5network5:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dbg:amd64:
  libc6-dbg:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.

  dpkg: error processing package libc6-dbg:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up tzdata (2022a-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another    process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
  installed tzdata package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:
  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb depends on locales | locales-all; however:
  Package locales is not configured yet.
  Package locales-all is not installed.

  dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-en-gb (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:
  bluez depends on kmod; however:
  Package kmod is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up libpam0g:amd64 (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3) ...
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another   process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package libpam0g:amd64 (--configure):
  installed libpam0g:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
  cups-daemon depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
  Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:amd64:
  libssl-dev:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package libssl-dev:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of util-linux:
  util-linux depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
  Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.23); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
  samba-common-bin depends on samba-common (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu0.21.04.2);  however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of passwd:
  passwd depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
  Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mount:
  mount depends on util-linux (>= 2.30.1-0ubuntu4~); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package mount (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:
  libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
  Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl4:amd64:
  libcurl4:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package libcurl4:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:amd64:
  libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.9); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.

  dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcryptsetup12:amd64:
  libcryptsetup12:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package libcryptsetup12:amd64 (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:
  language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on locales (>= 2.3.6); however:
   Package locales is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.8~20.04.1) ...
  debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another     process: Resource temporarily unavailable
  dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
  installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned   error exit status 1
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9-dnsutils:
  bind9-dnsutils depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

  dpkg: error processing package bind9-dnsutils (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sbsigntool:
  sbsigntool depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
  Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package sbsigntool (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools-core:
   initramfs-tools-core depends on kmod; however:
   Package kmod is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools-core (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
    package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
    reinstall it before attempting configuration
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9-host:
    bind9-host depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
    Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package bind9-host (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssl:
    openssl depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1); however:
    Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package openssl (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
     Setting up xserver-xorg-legacy (2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) ...
     debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another  process: Resource temporarily unavailable
    dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-legacy (--configure):
    installed xserver-xorg-legacy package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libicu-dev:amd64:
    libicu-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
    Package libc6-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
    Package libc-dev is not installed.
    Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libicu-dev:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up libpam-runtime (1.3.1-5ubuntu4.3) ...
    debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another       process: Resource temporarily unavailable
    dpkg: error processing package libpam-runtime (--configure):
    installed libpam-runtime package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1:
    policykit-1 depends on libpam-systemd; however:
    Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.
    policykit-1 depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1); however:
    Package libpam0g:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package policykit-1 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmount-dev:amd64:
    libmount-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
    Package libc6-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
    Package libc-dev is not installed.
    Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libmount-dev:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64:
    libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libfreerdp2-2 (>= 2.1.0+dfsg1); however:
    Package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
    libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.1.0+dfsg1); however:
    Package libwinpr2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libkmod2:amd64:
    libkmod2:amd64 depends on libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0); however:
    Package libssl1.1:amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package libkmod2:amd64 (--configure):
    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: too many errors, stopping
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    mysql-server-8.0
    linux-base
    initramfs-tools
    cups-bsd
    libssl1.1:amd64
    libssl1.1:i386
    libfreerdp2-2:amd64
    libpython3.8-dbg:amd64
    libsasl2-modules:amd64
    libsasl2-modules:i386
    rsyslog
    ufw
    php7.4-cli
    samba-common
    kmod
    apache2-bin
    locales
    libwinpr2-2:amd64
    libqt5network5:amd64
    libc6-dbg:amd64
    tzdata
    libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
    bluez
    libpam0g:amd64
    cups-daemon
    libssl-dev:amd64
    util-linux
    pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
    samba-common-bin
    passwd
    mount
    libpam-systemd:amd64
    libcurl4:amd64
    libc6-dev:amd64
    libcryptsetup12:amd64
    language-pack-gnome-en-base
    ubuntu-advantage-tools
    bind9-dnsutils
    sbsigntool
    initramfs-tools-core
    virtualbox-dkms
    bind9-host
    openssl
    xserver-xorg-legacy
    libicu-dev:amd64
    libpam-runtime
    policykit-1
    libmount-dev:amd64
    libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64
    libkmod2:amd64
     Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Comment: Your output says that you are trying to install an older version of MySQL over a newer version, which is rarely wise. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: why dpkg??? That command requires you to install ALL required packages yourself. Pleae use either apt to install the supported mysql or use a tarball and place mysql in /opt/ (that version has all packages linked in /opt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t)

Comment: Thanks Karel that worked.