Can I get help with playing a DVD movie?
I am trying to play a DVD movie using VLC.
I did this.
sudo apt install libdvdcss2

Then this.
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
[sudo] password for andy: 
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Can someone help me ?
Thanks.

the solution to this is posted prior to this forum...  https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t

Thanks. The 'sudo fuser' answer solved the lock problem. But I still can not play a DVD movie.

Have you installed the restricted extras and addons?  Is your DVD encrypted?  Are you certain your hardware is functioning?  Is your dvd drive internal or external-usb?  Can VLC play an mp4 off your hard drive? What is your system hardware and Ubuntu release?

I have installed the restricted extras and addons. DVD is not encrypted. VLC can play an mp4 from my hard drive. Ubuntu_Mate 20.04 DVD drive is internal.

1/ Using the file manager, can you get to the video files on your DVD? (usually, these are vob files). Can VLC play these files?   2/ In Settings, Removable Media, is VLC the default for the DVD player?   3/ Have you tried installing a different DVD software, such as smplayer ?

@rob grune You may be on to something. I tried installing smplayer and got this. libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: apt-get check failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

1/ Have you installed synaptic?  It's a great GUI for deb files.  2/ If the VLC and SMPlayers are not installed from deb files, suggest you purge whatever files you attempted to install. 3/ Then use synaptic to find smsplayer and install.  If from this the smplayer plays, then vlc should play also after a fresh deb install. 4/ fyi, Use synaptic to fix broken packages and other problems.

@rob grune Synaptic shows no broken packages. sudo apt purge vlc gave me libdvd-pkg: apt-get check failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting... Would reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS help with this mess ?

I know suggesting a fresh install is considered a cop-out by others here, but often is an expedient, depending upon how sophisticated is the first install. Debugging problems can require days or weeks of frustrations. A fresh install is maybe 30 minutes and is assured to create a working machine. But restore of TB of data can take much time, which why I advocate the install drive be partitioned from the data drive, to avoid harming data files. You be the judge.

@rob grune You make some good points. I have my important  stuff backed up to a second drive. I will do a fresh install. :-)

backed up or copied?  Generally, I advise to format the external disk to exfat or ntsc, then copy the files. This ensures portability to other machines.

@rob grune My external disk is fat32 and files are copied to it.

has the fresh install resolved your issues?

I installed UM 24.04.
I still can not play a DVD movie using VLC. :slight_smile:
Synaptic Package Manager shows no broken packages.
I can play a .mp4, so I do not think it is a hardware issue.
I am not ready to give up on this.

@rob grune I can play a DVD movie using VLC. From tkn on ubuntu-mate.community sudo apt install libdvdread8 libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg

so the fresh install resolved the broken packages?  and installing the dvd library solved the issue?

I installed UM 24.04. I then did this. sudo apt install libdvdread8 libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg and it solved the issue. @rob grune

You can resolve the problem by running the following command:
sudo fuser -v -k /var/cache/debconf/config.dat

This command checks which program is using the following file (/var/cache/debconf/config.dat) and kills the process.
Eventually if it doesn't work you can kill the process using the sudo kill command.
